# kendo grid is taking more time to load when using kendo editor inside a template

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I am trying to load the documents on click of a button which is inside a grid but it is creating a new pages for every row and it is taking more time how to resolve it using kendo editor template or another specific methods.

```js
// open window
function openWin(id) {
    var myWindow = $("#" + id);
    var did = id.replace("win", "doc");
    console.log("Value from DID", did);
    var rid = Number(id.replace("win", ""));
    kendo.ui.progress($(".k-window"), true);
    myWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: JSON.stringify(rid),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) {

            kendo.ui.progress($(".k-window"), false);
            $("#" + did).data("kendoEditor").value(data);


        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error occured!!");
        }
    });
}

// column definition
{
    field: "Document",
    template: docTemplateFunction,
    title: "Document Intake",
    width: "250px",
    editable: "inline"
}

// template definition
function docTemplateFunction(dataItem) {
    var input = '<div id="win' + dataItem.id + '"><textarea id="doc' + dataItem.id + '" style="width:100%;" aria-label="editor"></textarea></div><button class="k-button" onclick="openWin(' + "'win" + dataItem.id + "'" + ')">Open Doc</button><span class="k-button k-state-disabled doc-btn"><i class="red k-icon k-i-close k-state-disabled"></i></span>';
    return input;
}
```

Comment: I do not agree with your approach. From a UI perspective, a grid is not designed to show a textarea, this is just bad UI design. Are you open to a different approach?

Comment: Yes I am open to a different approach

Comment: Before I post, I wanted to get confirmation if you would prefer a single page application approach or a modal/dialog window approach.

Comment: I would prefer modal/dialog window approach.

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://dojo.telerik.com/ixIDOzaF

Comment: Thank you for the solution. but the button inside the grid is not triggering for the second time. please guide on this issue

Comment: My apologies, I forget the Kendo Dialog does that. Take a look at this example that checks if the dialog exists first: https://dojo.telerik.com/ixIDOzaF/2

Comment: Thanks its working fine. I have one more issue will you please help me to solve that. How to get the dynamic row id from the kendo grid.

Comment: In my example, if you look inside the click event of the button you'll see where I am setting the value `var data = this.dataItem(tr);`. After that declaration you can reference the id by using `data.id`